# Choosing the right class at runtime

Tags: object-oriented-design

This is a general software design question. My program is written in Java, but I suppose my question applies to any object-oriented programming language. The best way for me to explain my situation is with an example.

In applications like LibreOffice and MS Office, the user chooses a program option when launching the software. For example, in LibreOffice, you have to choose Writer, Calc, Draw, Impress, etc. before you can start using the program. In MS Office, it's Word, Excel, PowerPoint, etc.

My program is sort of like that. It has a main `JFrame` class that sets an overridden `JPanel` as its content pane when the program launches. So far, there are three choices of `JPanel`, and the program chooses between them with a simple conditional statement:

```
public MyJFrame(String editorType, int numPages) {
    ...

    if (editorType.equals("order-editor"))
        setContentPane(new OrderEditor(this));
    else if (editorType.equals("order-finder"))
        setContentPane(new OrderFinder(this));
    else if (editorType.equals("article-writer"))
        setContentPane(new ArticleWriter(this, numPages));

    ...
}
```

So everything is hard-coded into the `JFrame` class. When I override another `JPanel`, I have to go back to the `JFrame` class to add another `else if` clause to the constructor. Is there a better way to do this? The only way I can imagine doing it programmatically would be compiling code at runtime, and that seems like the wrong way to go.

The `editorType` string is a command-line argument to the main function. I could pass a `JPanel` object to the constructor instead, but I would still have to check the arguments to `main` before choosing the appropriate class. I'm beginning to think there's no other way to do this, but I'll leave this question up just in case.

Here's an example of my `main` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // calls private static String getEditorType(String[] args)
    // to parse the program input

    String editorType = getEditorType(args);
    if (editorType == null) {
        System.out.println("Invalid editor type.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int[] numPages = {-1};
    if (editorType.equals("article-writer"))

        // calls a similar static function to parse input
        numPages[0] = getNumPages(args);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JFrame frame = new MyJFrame(editorType, numPages[0]);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: And just where are you getting that editor type string from?  Any good reason it couldn't be passing us a new OrderEditor() or a new OrderEditorBuilder()?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @chris Look at Class.forName() to lookup classes by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get rid of that `numPages`. The `OrderEditor`, `OrderFinder` and `ArticleWriter` should implement common interface, that allows them to parse their own arguments. This is so that if arguments of any of those change, you don't have to change the whole initialization logic.

Second thing to do is to create dictionary where key is the `editorType` and value is either function that creates the instance or interface that allows creation of the instance.

I would actually opt in for the interface, because then argument parsing can be moved into it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought about creating something like HashMap<String, MyPanelBuilder> where MyPanelBuilder would be an interface that calls the appropriate JPanel constructor. I'll set it up this way.